# Forcing completion of CompletableFuture away from the current thread

Tags: java, android, concurrency, opengl-es, completable-future

My methods run operations on an ExecutorService using methods like `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` and its like, then, using chaining methods, further operations are chained before the resulting CF is returned to the caller, like so:

```java
public CompletableFuture<Void> myCoolOperation(int arg) {
    return CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() -> this.myCoolInternalOperation(arg), myCoolInternalExecutorService).
        .thenRun(this::myCoolChainedMethod);
}
```

Pretty simple, right? And works just fine, but since Java's concurrency library seems to come with the built-in assumption that all threads are created equal, my caller gets a future object that will allow running subsequent operations on `myCoolInternalExecutorService`, which I consider to be an implementation detail of my class that I would like to avoid leaking.

The reason for this is that Android generally does not treat all threads as equal, and has at least two threads that play special roles: the main/UI thread and any thread to which a GLES context is bound (and therefore GL operations must be executed only on that thread).

Is there any kind of hack that would allow me to avoid leaking the internal thread/threadpool altogether, or at least make non-async continuation methods used by my caller use a different thread by default?

Alternatively, is there an alternative to CF that I can use on Android to accomplish this instead? I tried RxJava but it seems even less suitable for this use case.

Thanks!